# Getting NullPointerException while reading Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to read values from  SQLite database but getting `NullPointerException` when I execute

```
   private final String DB_NAME = "UserDb";
   private final String TABLE_NAMES = "tbluser"; 
   SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
   Cursor c=null;
   String deviceDec;  
   c= sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * from " +TABLE_NAMES+" where did='"+deviceDec+"' ",null);
```

Please suggest me why I am getting the exception because in one function it is running but in other it is not and also I am getting the deviceDec value that I have checked in Log.

Comment: please paste your table structure.

Comment: this is how i am creating the database                                                            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, did TEXT, idate DATE, edate DATE)");
                                        sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +TABLE_NAME +"(did,idate,edate) Values ('"+IMEI+"','"+fDate+"','"+feDate+"');");

Comment: but the problem is In the activity where i am creating the database is working file but in other activity i have to just read the database there it is throwing null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

May be your `sampleDB;` is null.

so first you have init that object like as

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = new SQLiteDatabase(Your Param);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to initiate DB..

```
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB=context.getReadableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 1):

open database before selecting data from it.

```
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    return myDataBase;
}
```

this will return dataabase.. and then use 
returnedDb.rawQuery("");